# "Your Redis network connection is performing extremely poorly" warning on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

When runnning sidekiq locally (with or without cron jobs) I get this warning:

```
WARN: Your Redis network connection is performing extremely poorly.
Last RTT readings were [206649, 404660, 207362, 508564, 508909], ideally these should be < 1000.
Ensure Redis is running in the same AZ or datacenter as Sidekiq.
```

I have been researching and looking at my redis server but I cannot make sense of this. What could be reasons for this so slow on my local machine?

Checking the latency with `redis-cli --latency-history` results in this (which I think is fine but correct me if I am wrong).

```
min: 0, max: 1, avg: 0.14 (1352 samples) -- 15.01 seconds range
min: 0, max: 3, avg: 0.15 (1351 samples) -- 15.01 seconds range
min: 0, max: 1, avg: 0.15 (1341 samples) -- 15.00 seconds range
min: 0, max: 2, avg: 0.15 (1349 samples) -- 15.00 seconds range
min: 0, max: 3, avg: 0.16 (1348 samples) -- 15.01 seconds range
min: 0, max: 5, avg: 0.17 (1346 samples) -- 15.00 seconds range
min: 0, max: 70, avg: 0.21 (1340 samples) -- 15.01 seconds range
min: 0, max: 59, avg: 0.23 (1337 samples) -- 15.00 seconds range
```

Thanks for your help, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4824. I think you can ignore it, it's a sidekiq thing which shouldn't matter on your local.

Comment: I do have the same issue, of course Redis in in the same DC. Logs show `Current RTT is 105309 µs, ideally this should be < 1000` but I don't understand why we should have such delay